# ran fsck on a mounted partition, now centos 5 won't boot

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, corruption, fsck

Yes, I very stupidly ran fsck on a mounted parition. Immediate regret.

What's happening now is I see grub, it starts booting centos 5, then it says:

```
bin/sh: ro: no such file or directory   kernel panic
```

I've booted with a clonezilla livecd and noticed that it detected all 5 partitions on the HDD. Could that mean that the partitions are okay but the OS files are corrupted?

Anybody know how I might fix this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry no quick answer.

The broken partition will be the one you did the `fsck` on.  The other non-fsck'd partitions should be fine.

Looks like you might have killed the root partition containing critical system files.

You can reboot from a Linux Rescue CD and check the other partitions to see if they are ok.  I'd back up any data from them.  Then reinstall the OS, preserve the data partitions if you are allowed but the data in needed systems partitions will likely be overwritten.  Restore necessary from the backups you made using both your own and the ones made with the rescue CD.

Comment: just for curiousity, what is the downgrade for?

Comment: who did the downgrade?

Comment: Ended up reverting to a backup

Comment: GREAT.....too many people forget to backup things so when disasters happen they are unprepared.